# Returning a deffered promise within another deffered

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

Consider the following:

```
function foo(){
  // Returns the jQuery deffered below.
    var urlToUse;
     $.ajax({
          url:'someUrl',
          success:function(res){urlToUse= res;}
     }).then(function(){
       return  $.ajax({url:urlToUse,
             success:function(){
                //Do something 
             }
         }); // I want to return this deffered object!
     })
}
```

Is there a way to return the promise within the promise?

Comment: I think what you want is a promise which resolves when second ajax is done...

Comment: @Vishwanath right, which is exactly what the Promise returned from `.then()` will do.

Comment: I might be getting confused here. Promise returned from `.then` will do the trick. But `foo` is not returning anything here. And I guess thats the problem OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @Vishwanath yes, this is the issue.

Comment: Hmm. Answer from Eric should work for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to return the promise returned by the outer $.ajax chain. Replace `$.ajax...` with `return $.ajax...`

You can actually write this much more concisely, since `.then` is a replacement for using `success:` callbacks

```
function foo(){
     // | This return is all you need to add to make your current code work      
     // V
     return $.ajax({url:'someUrl'}).then(function(res) {
         var urlToUse = res;
         return $.ajax({url: urlToUse});
     }).then(function(secondRes) {
         //Do something
         return "Got: " + secondRes;
     });
}
```

Which you can then use as:

```
foo().then(function(finalRes) {

}, function(someError) {

});
```

Comment: I think this is the one I was looking for. Will test tommorow!

Answer (score 3):

You just did. There are 3 things that can happen in a jQuery `then`:

If you don't return anything at all to `then`, the next chained then will resolve with the same value as the previously attached `then`.

```
$.ajax(...)
  .then(function(result){ // result = 5
    // This block executes when the first AJAX resolves
    // Do nothing
  })
  .then(function(result){ // result = 5
    // This block executes right after the previous `then`
    // and still uses the same resolved value
  });
```

If *you return a promise* (like from a jQuery `ajax` or `Deferred`), the next chained `then` will resolve when that returned promise resolves.

```
$.ajax(...)
  .then(function(firstAjaxResult){
    // This block executes when the first AJAX resolves

    // Return a promise
    return $.ajax(...);
  })
  .then(function(secondAjaxResult){
    // This will resolve when the second AJAX resolves
  });
```

If you return anything other than a promise, the next chained then will resolve with the value returned by the previous `then` instead of the original value.

```
$.ajax(...)
  .then(function(result){ // result = 5
    // This block executes when the first AJAX resolves

    // Return a modified result
    return result * 3;
  })
  .then(function(newResult){ // newResult = 15
    // This block executes right after the previous `then`
    // but resolves with the modified value
  });
```

Comment: Wouldn't the function return undefined, since deffered is still not resolved?

Comment: @Skarlinski the `.then()` function returns a separate Promise from the one that your callback returns. That Promise *waits for your promise to resolve*, thus effectively doing exactly what you want.

Comment: @Skarlinski `$.ajax(...).then(fun1).then(fun2)` will mean that `fun2` will be run when the promise returned by `fun1()` is fulfilled.

Comment: Note that this behavior breaks in 3.0 which spec-conforms to promises.